# Query on de-compilation of a simple program

Tags: reverse-engineering

Here is a simple program, I have pasted assembly generated for x86_64 along with C source code.

```
int main()
{
  4004b4:   55                      push   %rbp
  4004b5:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
    int array[10];

    array[0] = 5;
  4004b8:   c7 45 d0 05 00 00 00    movl   $0x5,-0x30(%rbp)

    return 0;
  4004bf:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
}
```

I am aware of program de-compilation tools like IDA-pro, dcc etc but I do not know how those programs can figure out details like array bounds. More generically, is there any way to figure out *looking at just assembly* that,

`movl   $0x5,-0x30(%rbp)` is actually an operation on `int array[10]`? I can see that if the program is compiled with `-g` i.e. with debug information then `objdump` does show source code and we can figure it out. How do commercial decompilers figure out this when the binaries lack debug details?

Comment: I deleted my answer since you *already know* that this is not possible with your example. I'd suggest you elaborate your question, and switch to a different example. Good luck.

Comment: Actually, your answer was helpful and might have benefited folks who are totally new to this aspect. Coming back to my original query, the question could be as generic as "How do de-compilers figure out symbolic information when there is no debug data in the binary?" If anyone has any pointers to the internals of a de-compiler it would be great. The example quoted above just talks about one specific case so the question does not appear vague.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can figure that out in your example. There's too little code in that function.

If it were a bigger function that used the array multiple times you might find some tips pointing to that. Like base address + different offset popping in and out through out the generated machine code.

Weak assumption:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        array[i] = i * 2;
```

This would allow you  to assume, by looking at the generated code, that you're dealing with an array of 10 ints.

Stronger case:

```
int *array = NULL;
array = malloc(10 * sizeof *array);
if (array == NULL)
        return ENOMEM;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        array[i] = i * 2;
```

This would make the fact that you're dealing with an array of 10 ints a certainty.

In your case you only have the raw information: the function allocated 10 * sizeof(int) bytes on the stack. (Which actually depends on the optimizer as well, but that's another topic).

So it's all about the heuristics and code pattern recognition algorithms that programs like IDA use to feed you as much reliable information as possible.

The rest is up to the reverser's experience.

Comment: Paul, thanks for your answer. As you pointed out the issue is to figure out the details for stack variables. Any pointers on what kind of heuristics IDA uses? I understand that they might be proprietary but any pointers on any open source tool which uses similar heuristics would be great.

Comment: IDA uses a lot of algorithms, I can't enumerate them. But you can start by looking at the papers published around the subject. I recommend [Thomas Reps](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~reps/) work on static analysis and also [Lim's](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~reps/#lim_thesis) Ph.D. thesis. You can also look at ollydbg, edbg and objdump and see how they do some of their basic tricks. Another point of research is the IDA community plugins that can be found at openrce and throughout the web. Hope this helps you getting started.